# Invariant Probability of Discrete Time MC from Continuous Time Markov Chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given rates α  of an irreducible continuous-time MC on finite state space and told that π is the invariant probability measure of this chain, we define a discrete time MC as having transition probabilities p(x,y) = α(x,y)/α(y).

I need to find the invariant probability of this discrete time chain in terms of π and α.

---

I'm not quite sure where to start.  I tried just drawing out the NxN matrix and computing the invariant probability by hand, but I'm hoping for a better way to do this.